# Android automatic SQL insert

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

How can I create a DB table and fill it up with some data onto application startup?I have a `init_sql.sql` file with create table and insert statements but only `CREATE TABLE` is executed so I have my table but it is empty.

```
init_sql.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Event (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   time TEXT NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   description TEXT NOT NULL,
   additional_info TEXT,
   stage CHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Event (name, time, description, stage)
VALUES ('13:30 - 14:30', 'koncert Blue tone Band', 
 'Mladá, energická jazzfunková kapela Blue tone Band Vás pobaví a rozhýbe zaručeně každého absolventa!', 'mainStage');
```

I verified that this file is correct by issuing `sqlite3 myDb.db < init_sql.sql`, this creates the table and inserts data.

My SQLHelper looks like this

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME = "alumni.db";

private Context context;

public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 6);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.init_sql);
    try {
        String sqlString = convertStreamToString(stream);
        db.execSQL(sqlString);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //TODO
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Event;");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

And I am using it inside my DAO class like `new SQLiteHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();`

So any ideas what could I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execSql` executes a single SQL command.

When you want to execute multiple commands, you have to execute them separately.

A better idea might be to ship the precreated database with the app.
(In that case, consider using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).)

Comment: Ahaaa, stupid me, I just assumed it can also execute batch and didn't look into documentation.